# UIBarButtonItem tintColor stopped working

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

For some reason I can't use UINavigationBar on my view and I use UIToolBar instead. I was using dummy left button with clear tintColor and title button with black tintColor to properly center the title and hide the dummy left bar button, but it's not working anymore and both the dummy left button and the title button get either the main tintColor or if I disable them, they become gray.

How can I make them ideally disabled as buttons and set the proper tintColor (clear and black)?

```
- (void)addToolbar
{
    CGFloat barHeight = 44.0;
    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.size.width - barHeight, self.view.bounds.size.height, barHeight)];

    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpaceButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                                initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                target:nil action:nil];

    // Done button on the right
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(done)];

    // dummy button on the left to have centered title
    UIBarButtonItem *dummyButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:nil action:nil];
    dummyButtonItem.enabled = NO;
    dummyButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // title button
    UIBarButtonItem *titleButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title text here" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    titleButtonItem.enabled = NO;
    titleButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    // set toolbar items
    toolbar.items = @[dummyButtonItem,flexibleSpaceButtonItem, titleButtonItem, flexibleSpaceButtonItem,doneButtonItem];

    [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
}
```

Comment: Did you tried to override `BarButtonItem` Class

Comment: No, the code above was working fine and suddenly stop working.

Comment: @MartinKoles if it was working fine you changed something else that broke this

Comment: @elio.d You were right, see my own answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify a tint for a view, the tint is automatically propagated to all subviews in the view’s hierarchy. Because UIWindow inherits from UIView, you can specify a tint color for the entire app by setting the window’s tint property using code like this:

Under `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
window.tintColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
```

Source - [iOS Transitions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH15-SW1) . Check it out under **Using Tint Color** section

Comment: Resolved, see my own answer. You helped me to solved that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your feedback I found that by doing this in AppDelegate:

```
self.window.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:59/255.0 blue:48/255.0 alpha:1.0];
[[UITextField appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:66/255.0 green:107/255.0 blue:242/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
```

the second line causes my issue. I now need to find out why did I put the second line there :). Thanks for your help.

Comment: I didn't even get that. Why you are changing the appearance of `UITextField`?

Comment: I have some login textFields in tableView and guess I needed them to be gray. I will look into that.

Comment: In the login part of the app, I need the cursor in the textField to be system blue color, and not system red as all other UI elements. I was tweaking the cursor color in the second line.

Comment: UITextField.appearance and UITextView.appearance both seem to break UIBarButtonItem tints, even those set in Storyboard. Confusing and frustrating bug.